# can't update repositories Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, updates, 13.10, update-manager

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I receive the following error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/Release
Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong  sources.list entry or malformed file)
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So why do you have debian repositories to begin with?

Comment: Because UBUNTU is debian.

Comment: No, it is not and neither is supported mixing repositories.

Comment: I am afraid I am 100% correct. Go here http://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros  or here for more precise info http://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros#ubuntu and you will see that Ubuntu is indeed based on the Debian distro.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly should not mix Debian and Ubuntu repositories. Some of the packages in either one of them will have different depends.

The fact that Ubuntu derives from Debian does not mean you can mix the repositories. This *usually* fails.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update Ubuntu repositories, if you're using Ubuntu 13.10 and you got your repositories messed up follow this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: It is not in the Ubuntu tab in the repositories but rather in the Other Software tab which was selected by default after upgrading from version 12.04. I have gone to the URL listed and the directory Ubuntu is looking for in the file is not there. It may be an older version of the list. Perhaps Ubuntu needs to update this file to reflect the information it is looking for. Or update the Software and Updates program correctly. I have to deselect that from the repository in order to stop getting this error. It occurs both with apt-update as well as the Software and Updates program.

Comment: What you're trying to update it's not Supported Ubuntu Repository it's Unsupported Ubuntu Repository and by default it can be disabled. The thing it's based on Debian alike, doesn't really makes you Multiverse. Ubuntu uptades its repositories from Supported Repositories = Main and Restricted and Unsupported Repositories = Universe and Multiverse, in this case your problem description equals to Unsupported Repositories, so make sure you got everything enabled and configured to use Unsupported Repositories.